# Audio is not allowed for specified platform

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Building a chrome extension and I used the permission audio in manifest.json. **
The about error shown `audio is not allowed for specified platform.` Any solution for this?

```
"permissions": [
      "input",
      "audio","activeTab", 
      "proxy", "storage", 
      "declarativeContent"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Chrome allows this API on ChromeOS only.

> The `chrome.audio`  API is provided to allow users to
> get information about  and control the audio devices attached to the
> system. This API is currently  only available in kiosk mode for
> ChromeOS.

([Link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/audio/))